# Use level order to change value of a factor in R

Tags: r

I'm used to working in Stata and SPSS where you can add value labels to a variable and still make changes to the variable using the underlying numeric value. In R, once I convert a variable to a factor, it seems like I can't use the numeric value any longer to update the values of the variable. Is there a way around this? If I have a factor with long labels, I don't want to have to type out the full label whenever I want to update any of the values. Any help is appreciated!

```
factor.demo <- data.frame(var1 = 1:20, var2 = rep(c(1,2,3,4),5))
factor.demo$var2 <- factor(factor.demo$var2, levels = c(1,2,3,4), labels = c("Level 1", "Level 2", "Level 3", "Level 4"))
factor.demo$var2[2]
[1] Level 2
Levels: Level 1 Level 2 Level 3 Level 4
factor.demo$var2[2] <- "Level 3"
factor.demo$var2[2]
1] Level 3
Levels: Level 1 Level 2 Level 3 Level 4
factor.demo$var2[2] <- 4
Warning message:
In `[<-.factor`(`*tmp*`, 2, value = c(1L, NA, 3L, 4L, 1L, 2L, 3L,  :
  invalid factor level, NA generated
```

Comment: Please trim your code to make it easier to find your problem. Follow these guidelines to create a [minimal reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example).

Answer (score 0):

The simplest way is to get the value of the factor and assign it to the element:

```r
> factor.demo$var2[2] <- levels(factor.demo$var2)[4]
> factor.demo$var2[2]
[1] Level 4
```

Without resorting to shenanigans with the C API, you're out of luck.